# Getting an Error while locating an element using xpath in Selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a link (Which looks like a tab button) using `Xpath` but getting an error.

This is the `html` snippet :

```html
<div id="tile_8" style="height: 93px; width: 26%; background-color: rgb(45, 87, 19); color: white; position: relative; float: left; margin: 10px; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1; border: 2px solid white;" class="divAppList-shadow" onmouseover="mouseOvering(event,'8')" onmouseout="mouseOuting(event,'8')">
 <b>
 <span style="font-size:medium; z-index:1; color:white;">Suggestion Scheme</span>
 </b><br>
 <span style="text-align:justify; z-index:1;color:white;">There is always a better way of doing a thing. You only can suggest it for us to Improve.</span>
 </div>
```

I have tried the following code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div")).click();
```

This is the Error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div"}
>   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.87)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.27.440174
>   (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 412 milliseconds For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45
>   -0700' System info: host: 'tmlpnedtp061674', ip: '172.22.84.78', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174
>   (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\AMITPA~1.TTL\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11224_7493},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=54.0.2840.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}] Session ID:
>   2bb2aa6d378f2c0f6ec720a9ee87068c
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div}   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:473)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
>     at testProj001.CordysUpgradeDemo.main(CordysUpgradeDemo.java:19)

Screenshot of the Site::
[image]

In the Screenshot as you can see i am trying to click on The Suggestion Scheme Button Link

Comment: Please help will be appreciated as i am new to selenium automation.

Comment: Share `HTML` code for mentioned button

Comment: You are using positional `xpath` which would not be more stable, for better solution you need to share relevant HTML..

Comment: Can i share you the HTML here if that would help??

Comment: @AmitPandey  you can share HTML after editing your question..

Comment: <div id="tile_8" style="height: 93px; width: 26%; background-color: rgb(45, 87, 19); color: white; position: relative; float: left; margin: 10px; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1; border: 2px solid white;" class="divAppList-shadow" onmouseover="mouseOvering(event,'8')" onmouseout="mouseOuting(event,'8')"><b><span style="font-size:medium; z-index:1; color:white;">Suggestion Scheme</span></b><br><span style="text-align:justify; z-index:1;color:white;">There is always a better way of doing a thing. You only can suggest it for us to Improve.</span></div>

Comment: Abve is the HTML code from which i got the Xpath through firepath

Comment: @AmitPandey `Suggestion Scheme` is the button text??

Comment: @AmitPandey what about it's id attribute value??.. is this unique and fixed??.. if it is , you can locate it as `By.id('tile_8')`..

Comment: Could you add screenshot of page?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not waiting for the page to load completely.
Try to wait for the page to completely load before trying to click on it. If the xpath is correct, then it has to be that.

To test, go to the webpage using Chrome..press F12 to open the developer's tools. Go to the console tab and type in the following: `$x("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div")` check the results. if it returns the correct element, then you have the correct xpath. If not, try the following:

1. `//div[@id='tile-8']`
2. `//div[@id='tile-8']/span[text()='Suggestion Scheme']`
3. `//span[text()='Suggestion Scheme']`

If option 1 works, just use `By.id("tile-8")` instead of `By.xpath()`

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have been using an autogenerated Xpath from firepath. I guess so.

Most of the times those Xpath will have browser compatability issue. Start writing your dynamic Xpath and before using that xpath in script make sure the xpath is correct by checking it in Firebug or in Chrome developer option.

**Steps to navigate to Developer option in chrome:**

1. Open chrome and navigate to the application.
2. Press F12.
3. Now you will see the developer console. Click `ctrl+F` and paste the Xpath you have written. If the Xpath is correct you will see the matching node results highlighted in `yellow color`.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thnkx for the answer,
But i have checked my Xpath with everything, and its coming correct but still the code is not able to click on the Button on which it should click actually.

Comment: I think you are getting dynamic xpath has one matching node from F12 but not able to click with it. Let me correct if i didnt get it correct. Then try to locate that element using locators apart from XPATH such as id. Also you can try to click the element using javascript as shoen below.                               // Assume driver is a valid WebDriver instance that
// has been properly instantiated elsewhere.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide anything to help you with your problem, I would give you -point, because now it is guessing game.

What can I say:

1. you did not provide full html of the page, only the button and it does not help. Since you are using Chrome DO NOT use firepath but the following:

   RMB (on button)->inspect->RMB on highlighted part->Copy->Copy Xpath

   And check if xpath is the same
2. If it is the same it may be caused by static method you are using, driver is not that intelligent to press the button that is behind something or you have to scroll down to press it. That's why I wanted screenshot

> If you need to scroll down page to press it add following before driver.findElement():

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,250)");  //250 is value of page scrolled, depends how much
```

As said, it is my guess since you didn't provide any information

Comment: The HTML code was too long for that to paste here, thats y was not able to provide it here. but really appreciate the ans u provioded.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Xpath installing "ChroPath"  on to the browser.